# Prolog double every other number in list

Tags: list, prolog

Hey guys I am trying to double every other number, but keep the rest of the list the same. Ex. `[2,2,2,2]` -> `[2,4,2,4]`

Here is what I have so far:

```
double_elements([H,H2|T], [X|Doubled_list]):-
    X is H2*2,
    double_elements(T, Doubled_list).
```

All it returns is `[4,4]`.

Answer (score 0):

What you've written is equivalent to

```
double_elements( A, B ) :-
    A = [ H,      H2 |  T ], 
    B = [    X       |     Doubled_list ],
             X is H2*2,
    double_elements(    T, Doubled_list ).
```

This means, you double each even-positioned element (`H2`) from the list `A` while putting the result `X` into the list `B`, but what about the elements in the odd positions, `H`?

You're just skipping those. To see it better, try your predicate with `[1,3,5,7]`. It will produce `[6,14]`.

Instead, include those `H`s in the "output" list `B`, as they are, without changing them.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a few cases:

- The empty list
- A list of length 1

Try something like this:

**To double the odd elements of the list:**

Where `[1,2,3,4]` becomes `[2,2,6,4]`

```
double_elements( []       , []        ) .
double_elements( [X]      , [X2]      ) :- X2 is X+X .
double_elements( [X,Y|Xs] , [X2,Y|Rs] ) :-
  X2 is X+X,
  double_elements(Xs,Rs)
  .
```

**To double the even elements of the list:**

Where `[1,2,3,4]` becomes `[1,4,3,8]`

```
double_elements( []       , []        ) .
double_elements( [X]      , [X]       ) .
double_elements( [X,Y|Xs] , [X,Y2|Rs] ) :-
  Y2 is Y+Y,
  double_elements(Xs,Rs)
  .
```

Comment: well I assume they already have the base case in their code because it wouldn't have run at all otherwise.  :)